# Linux split a file in two columns

Tags: linux, cut

I have the following file that contains 2 columns :

```
A:B:IP:80                  apples    
C:D:IP2:82                 oranges    
E:F:IP3:84                 grapes
```

How is possible to split the file in 2 other files, each column in a file like this:

File1

```
A:B:IP:80    
C:D:IP2:82    
E:F:IP3:84
```

File2

```
apples
oranges
grapes
```

Comment: What did you try for yourself? before posting here? Are the files whitespace separated or tab-separated

Comment: whitespace separated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl 1-liner using (abusing) the fact that `print` goes to `STDOUT`, i.e. file descriptor `1`, and `warn` goes to `STDERR`, i.e. file descriptor `2`:

```
 # perl -n means loop over the lines of input automatically
 # perl -e means execute the following code
 # chomp means remove the trailing newline from the expression

 perl -ne 'chomp(my @cols = split /\s+/); # Split each line on whitespace
           print $cols[0] . "\n";
           warn  $cols[1] . "\n"' <input 1>col1 2>col2
```

You could, of course, just use `cut -b` with the appropriate columns, but then you would need to read the file twice.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
awk '{print $1>"file1"; print $2>"file2"}' file
```

After runningl that command, we can verify that the desired files have been created:

```
$ cat file1
A:B:IP:80
C:D:IP2:82
E:F:IP3:84
```

And:

```
$ cat file2
apples
oranges
grapes
```

#### How it works

- `print $1>"file1"`

  This tells awk to write the first column to `file1`.
- `print $2>"file2"`

  This tells awk to write the second column to `file2`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an awk solution that'll work with any number of columns:

```
awk '{for(n=1;n<=NF;n++)print $n>"File"n}' input.txt
```

This steps through each field on the line and prints the field to a different output file based on the column number.

Note that blank fields -- or rather, lines with fewer fields than other lines, will cause line numbers to mismatch.  That is, if your input is:

```
A 1
B
C 3
```

Then `File2` will contain:

```
1
3
```

If this is a concern, mention it in an update to your question.

---

You could of course do this in bash alone, in a number of ways. Here's one:

```
while read -r line; do
  a=($line)
  for m in "${!a[@]}"; do
    printf '%s\n' "${a[$m]}" >> File$((m+1))
  done
done < input.txt
```

This reads each line of input into `$line`, then word-splits `$line` into values in the `$a[]` array. It then steps through that array, printing each item to the appropriate file, named for the index of the array (plus one, since bash arrays start at zero).